# How do I skip the Intro on Binding of Isaac?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I play the Binding of Isaac, and love the game. Though, I hate the very long intro. Is there anyway to skip it? Please tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All you have to do is hit the space bar.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on OS X.

Answer (score 5):

There is a problem on OS X, which can cause the spacebar to not make the game skip the intro in fullscreen mode:

> The problem is that on some Macs the game loses focus during the video when in full screen, therefore the spacebar will not work. Command - Tab to change focus, then reselect the game -- you will be able to use the spacebar then. You can avoid this by running the game in a window.

Source: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2146137

Answer (score 1):

You can also select turn the “prologue” off in options.